# Use of CA certificate in Certificate creation

Tags: ssl-certificate, private-key, csr, certificate-authority

I have read an [article](https://blog.atulr.com/localhost-https/) on how to create a local SSL certificate. The steps are basically as below: 
1. create a key pair
`openssl genrsa -des3 -out applicant.key 2048`
2. create a certificate signing request
`openssl req -new -sha256 -nodes -out applicant.csr -key applicant.key -config someCert.csr.cnf`
3. create a cert for the applicant using the ca.key(private key) and cacert.pem (CA certificate)
`openssl x509 -req -in applicant.csr -CA cacert.pem -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -out applicant.crt -days 500 -sha256 -extfile localdomain.v3.ext`

I got a few question regarding the steps.

a) When we create the key in step 1, is it a key pair or just private key?
b) When creating a certificate signing request in step 2, do we need a public key or private key?
c) When create a cert from CA, why do we need both ca private key and ca certificate? I believe the ca private key is used for digital signature, but what's the purpose of CA certificate?

Answer (score 0):

**When we create the key in step 1, is it a key pair or just private key?**

`applicant.key` contains both the public and private elements.  You can see them with `openssl rsa -text -nout -in applicant.key`,  or in a more basic form with `dumpasn1` or similar.

---

**When creating a certificate signing request in step 2, do we need a public key or private key?**

Both.  You need the public key as that is going to be certified by the CA.  You need the private key as you sign the CSR with this to provide Proof of Possession of the public key.

---

**When create a cert from CA, why do we need both its private key and ca certificate?**

Again, both.  You need the private key in order to sign the certificate.  You also need the CA certificate so that the CA can extract information used during the signing process from it.

As a minimum, this is the Subject field of the CA certificate which is used as the Issuer field of the signed certificate.

Another example is the AuthorityKeyIdentifier extension in the CA certificate, whose value is used as the SubjectKeyIdentfier extension in the applicant's certificate.

However, CAs are at liberty to use whatever they need.  For example, Microsoft CAs will check the expiry date on the CA certificate and not issue an applicant a certificate that expires past this date (it truncates the validity of the certificate).  In order to do that, it needs access to the CA certificate.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it clears most of my concepts. But I don't quite understand the answer to third question. Applicant gives the CSR to the CA, wanna get an applicant certificate from CA. CA will extract necessary information from CSR and create a cert with digital signature with its own private key. I though that's the end (which should be wrong). You mentioned that "CA signing the certificate can extract information used during the signing process". Are you talking about the CA cert and what's the information needed from CA certificate (not the CSR)? Can you give a more detail flow?